# ragged2e breaks soul package \textbf{} spacing

Tags: spacing, soul, letterspacing, ragged2e

If you compile the XeLaTeX below you will see the output is not-as-expected for the bold part of the text i.e. it is:

`underline underline boldboldbold`

In other words the spacing of the bold elements inside *soul*'s `\ul` is seemingly non-existent. One would expect:

`underline underline bold bold bold`

I have narrowed down the issue to the `ragged2d` package when using the Minion Pro font (although it is reproducible with other fonts). The problem also occurs with macros such as `\textit`.

The following demonstrates the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\ul{underline underline \textbf{bold bold bold}}
\end{document}
```

Having identified the problem, I noted one workaround is using `{\bfseries{}bold bold bold}` but that sometimes leads to "Reconstruction failed" error, and in any case I am curious as to what is going on here.

---

Another workaround, seemingly more robust than `bfseries`, is to end then re-start the underlining so that the `textbf` encapsulates the `ul` i.e. `\ul{underline underline }\textbf{\ul{bold bold bold}}`. Whenever the font changes, then, we may end then re-start the underlining.

Comment: I can cut the example down (preamble) `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}`

Comment: `soul` is a (horrible) hack.

Comment: @MartinSchröder And nobody should use underlining. ;-)

Comment: `soul` tricks `ragged2e` into believing the bold font is a monospaced font. The problem shows with _any_ font changing command in `\ul` - even with `\textrm`.  Please file a bug with the author of the `soul` package. :-p

Comment: @egreg: And of course not LaTeX's underlining.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Thanks for the comments. Is there a less-horrible alternative to soul to achieve underlining (esp. that spans multiple lines)?

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: Seriously: ConTeXt. :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Good to know. :o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is an incompatibility of packages `soul` and `ragged2e` about the handling of `\spaceskip`.

Package `soul` saves the interword space settings of the font in the skip register `\SOUL@spaceskip` in `\SOUL@start`. In the preamble of the `ul` driver, `\spaceskip` is set to `\SOUL@spaceskip`. Later `\spaceskip` is used in `\SOUL@uleveryspace` for setting the space: `\hskip\spaceskip`.

Package `ragged2e` loads package `everysel` to add its interword space modifications to suppress the stretch component. However, it resets
`\spaceskip` to zero, if ragging is not in force.

Now, a font switch to the bold font occurs inside the underlined text. If package `ragged2e` is loaded, then `\spaceskip` is set to zero. The `everyspace` handler of `soul`'s underline driver then sets `\hskip\spaceskip` as interword space, that means no space, because `\spaceskip` is zero.

The following example tries to fix the issue for `soul` drivers `ul` and `so`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
% for bold typewriter font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@inside@soul
\newif\if@inside@soul@ul
\g@addto@macro\SOUL@ulpreamble{%
  \@inside@soul@ultrue
}
\patchcmd\SOUL@start{\SOUL@preamble}{\@inside@soultrue\SOUL@preamble}
  {}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \protect\SOUL@start}}
\renewcommand{\@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont}{%
  \if@raggedtwoe@spaceskip
    \ifdim\fontdimen\thr@@\font=\z@\relax
      \if@inside@soul
        \if@inside@soul@ul
          \spaceskip\fontdimen\tw@\font
          \@minus\fontdimen4\font
        \fi
      \else
        \spaceskip\z@
      \fi
    \else
      \spaceskip\fontdimen\tw@\font
    \fi
  \else
    \if@inside@soul
      \if@inside@soul@ul
        \spaceskip\fontdimen\tw@\font
        \@plus\fontdimen\thr@@\font
        \@minus\fontdimen4\font
      \fi
    \else
      \spaceskip\z@
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ul{underline underline \textbf{bold bold bold}}\\
\so{letter spacing \textbf{bold bold bold}}

\RaggedRight\ttfamily
\ul{underline underline \textbf{bold bold bold}}\\
\so{letter spacing \textbf{bold bold bold}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]